# nokogiri excluded elements from select all by class

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm just trying to exclude a couple of child elements by class from a selection of all the children of a node

```
page.css('div.parent > *').each do |child|
  if (child["class"].content != 'this' && child["class"].content != 'that')
    array.push(child.text.to_s)
  end
end
```

I know this not the write syntax, but have been unable to find how to select an elements class, as opposed to selects and element *by* class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css) method gives you `Nokogiri::XML::Element` instances and those get most of their behavior from their [`Nokogiri::XML::Node`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Element.html) parent class. To get an attribute out of a Node, use `[]`:

```
page.css('div.parent > *').each do |child|
  if(!%w{this that}.include?(child['class']))
    array.push(child.text.to_s)
  end
end
```

You could also use `if(child['class'] != 'this' && child['class'] != 'that')` if that makes more sense to you.

However, `class` attributes can have multiple values so you might want to split them into pieces on whitespace:

```
exclude = %w{this that}
page.css('div.parent > *').each do |child|
  classes = (child['class'] || '').split(/\s+/)
  if((classes & exclude).length > 0)
    array.push(child.text.to_s)
  end
end
```

The [intersection](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000274) is just an easy way to see if the two arrays have any elements in common (i.e. `classes` contains anything that you want to exclude).

Comment: Thanks mu, that's what I was after. You forgot to close the `if` on the second line

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks, missing parenthesis added.

Comment: ah, thanks for the second block, that's probably a little more robust.