# Nokogiri: How can you exclude HTML attributes with certain class names?

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

If I want to parse a HTML block using Nokogiri in Ruby like this:

```
<th class="first">ancd</th>
<th>xyz</th>
<th>sdf</th>
```

How do I exclude the tag containing a certain class name? the "first" in this case.

Comment: Here is a similar SO Post that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102993/nokogiri-excluded-elements-from-select-all-by-class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors:

```
doc.css('th:not(.first)')
```

In this simple case, you can also use xpath:

```
doc.xpath('//th[not(@class="first")]')
```

The difference is that xpath requires an exact match in the class name. If you had the possibility of having multiple classes, e.g. `<th class="red first">` then the CSS selector will identify it, but the xpath won't (without making it a bit more complicated).

Edit: Just for reference, if you want the xpath that can select a class when there may be multiple classes on an element:

```
doc.xpath('//th[@class and contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class)," "), " first ")]')
```

Normally XPath is a lot more flexible than CSS selectors, but this is an HTML edge case that favors CSS.

Comment: Can you also exclude multiple class names? For example, if I had:
    
    `<th class='first'>xxy</th>`
    `<th class='second'>xxz</th>`

Comment: Sure, e.g. `doc.xpath('//th[not(@class="first") and not(@class="second")]')`